# How to implement attribute specific templates without redundancy

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm familiar with using templates that key off attributes as follows (e.g. key off of the presence of `foo`):

```
<xsl:template match="something[@foo]">
<xsl:template match="something[not(@foo)]">
```

However, if much of the content of these templates is the same, is there a better way that still uses templates, since the community appears to prefer them? Or is the solution to just use `xsl:choose`. It's clearly preferable not to write duplicate code that must be maintained in both templates.

EDIT:
Here's my specific set of templates:

```
<xsl:template match="item[not(@format)]">
  <td class="{current()/../@name}_col status_all_col">
  <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@units"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[@format]">
  <td class="{current()/../@name}_col status_all_col">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(current(), @format)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@units"/>
  </td>

</xsl:template>
```

and here's what I currently have using choose:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <td class="{current()/../@name}_col status_all_col">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@format">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(current(), @format)"/>
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:value-of select="@units"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The answer depends on the actual content of the two templates. -- P.S. There is nothing wrong with using  `xsl:choose`.

Comment: I added my specific templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use `xsl:choose` in this situation.

---

Just to demonstrate how you *could* use templates without code repetition:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <td class="{../@name}_col status_all_col">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="format"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@units"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(@format)]" mode="format">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[@format]" mode="format">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., @format)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I fail to see what advantage this would have. On the contrary, it suffers from the [GOTO syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism).

---

BTW, this may not be the best example, since I believe that supplying an empty string as the second argument of the `format-number()` function will result in the number being returned *as-is*.

So you could just use a single template to match all:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <td class="{../@name}_col status_all_col">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(current(), @format)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@units"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment about possibly not needing the branching behavior. However, it does turn out that I've got some non-number pieces of data and format-number was just returning "NaN" for those.

Comment: "*I've got some non-number pieces of data*" Ah, that makes sense. -- Note also that in XSLT 2.0 you could use `xsl:next-match`.